# Don't ".info" domains work with button functions?

Tags: dns, facebook-like, facebook-wall

On my new website, the like button doesn't work properly. I can like the page without any problem, but when I try to put the comment on it, every assets of [Open Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Open_Graph_protocol) tags drop off on the wall. Please check http://graphiccode.info/.

Well, I have installed like buttons many times at work, but this one doesn't work properly. I checked every aspects of the HTML code, and I think nothing is wrong here. 
I put the same HTML file on a different server and checked, but neither of them are working.
Since it works perfectly fine when I put the different domain on the same server, I think the `.info` domain is the reason why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem solved.

The problem was actually really simple. Days after I asked this question, it started working just fine. I guess that was only a timing issue. Maybe, right after you register for domain, og tags don't work properly I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The `.info` domain should be working in Facebook (at least mine is working as far as I know).
I think you should contact Facebook support directly for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try to contact them then.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your page metadata:

```
<meta name="description" content="This is the testdescription ihope it appears."
```

(eg, should be a closing > at the end).

Comment: But, it still doesn't show the whole og tag information on the wall.